# How to rotate text using CSS

Tags: html, css

Unable to rotate the text. The gray div width has to be 50. Using Chrome.

http://jsfiddle.net/NLfaz/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="divContactInfo">
    <div class="tabHeader">
        <span class="textRotate">My Contact Info</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.divContactIno
{
position:fixed;
    right:0;
    border:1px solid red;
    top:49%;
    width:350px;
    height:500px;
}
.divContactInfo .tabHeader
{
border:1px solid gray;
    width:50px;
    height:120px;
}
.textRotate
{
  -webkit-trasform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-trasform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Comment: your css is misspelled.. -->  trasform  <--

Comment: The text has to be in a single line, and the div width to be 50px. Is this possible.

Comment: check my answer for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your comment..  Try this

```
.textRotate {
    display: block;
    white-space: pre;
    left: 10px;
    margin-top: 80px;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rotate an inline element, and you need to spell `transform` correctly.

```
.textRotate {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Note that you also misspelled `divContactInfo` as `divContactIno`.

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/R7bQn/

Comment: Thank you , but the text has to be in single line. I would like the div width to stay 50 as I have to style it later.

Answer (score 1):

try add property`display` and then use Rotate:

```
.divContactInfo
{
position:fixed;
    right:0;
    border:1px solid red;
    top:49%;
    width:350px;
    height:500px;
}
.divContactInfo .tabHeader
{
border:1px solid gray;
    width:50px;
    height:120px;
}


.textRotate {
display:block;
/* Safari */
-webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Firefox */
-moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* IE */
-ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Opera */
-o-transform: rotate(-90deg);

/* Internet Explorer */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NLfaz/3/

Comment: Thank you , but the text has to be in single line. I would like the div width to stay 50 as I have to style it later.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .divContactInfo
    {
    position:fixed;
        right:0;
        border:1px solid red;
        top:49%;
        width:350px;
        height:500px;
    }
    .divContactInfo .tabHeader
    {
    border:1px solid gray;
        width:50px;
        height:120px;
    }
    .textRotate
    {
        display:block;
      -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
        -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
    }
```